# Why can't react-native apps use remote storage like MongoDB?

Tags: database, react-native

Why can't react-native apps use remote storage like MongoDB and can only use local storage databases?

Comment: Enough communication with the server is possible to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Localstorage and persisted backend db stores like mongo or mysql have different use cases, local storage is kind of temporary not very important data, just required to speed up app operations and reduce network calls to fetch data over and over.
It may also be used to store logs etc.

On the other hand, mongo or mysql or postgres like DB engines are meant to store data which is critical and we dont want to loose it in case say user losts his phone or anything like that.

**So both have completely different use cases, not to mention you CAN choose to use mongo or anyother remote DB to store the local app data, but that will be very costly in terms of development and user experience and not to mention running costs.**